# Why is the HTML element hiding behind javascript generated elements?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am having an issue where when I create an element (Ex: `div`) with JavaScript and then append that to the `div` with the class of `container` everything below the container class (which in this case is the image) goes straight up to the top. I would like to see the image in this case sit underneath the `div` with the `container` class. I honestly do not know why this is not working the way that I would think it would. I have made the exact same thing with pure html and css and it worked fine it is just when I create all of the elements with JavaScript were things do not look right.

Here is a [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Loweman/rgfw59e5/) with the same code as below.

```js
var container = document.getElementById('container');
var child = container.getElementsByClassName('block');
for (var i = 0; i < 21; i++) {
 var board = document.createElement('div');
  board.setAttribute('class', 'block');
  board.setAttribute('id', i + 1);
  document.getElementById('container').appendChild(board);
}
```

```css
#container {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  border: 2px solid red;
  width: 388px;
}

.block {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  margin-left: 8px;
  margin-top: 8px;
  float: left;
  border: 2px solid #95a5a6;
  width: 64px;
  height: 64px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>
<img src="https://placeimg.com/100/100/any">
```

Comment: `appendChild()` takes your div and then places it as the last child of the parent element that 's targeted..

Comment: How you want the image to be placed ? Get fixed inside all the boxes ?

Comment: @Nandan I would like the image to be placed outside the div container.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understand your question correctly, but I believe that your issue stems from the fact that your `#container` is `position: absolute`.

Absolutely positioned elements are taken out of the flow of the page, witch basically means that they don't take up any "space". Technically, its not the image that sits below `#containter`, its `#conainer` that sits above the image.

Solution: Give `#container` a `position: relative`. Also, give it an `overflow: hidden` or a clearfix to stop the `float: left` children from overflowing.

Comment: No problems at all! Happy coding! :)

Answer (score 1):

Please try following

```
#container {
 display: block;
 border: 2px solid red;
 width: 388px;
 min-height: 450px;
}
```